# Similar Master pages, best way to DRY?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have two similar master pages, basically they are pretty extensive, but the difference relies in one using

```
common content

<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    common content
</form>

common content
```

and the other being

```
common content

<dn:Form id="form1" runat="server">
    common content
</dn:Form>

common content
```

I was wondering how I could accomplish this, without having to create two master pages and just changing the form tags...

The way I currently though of doing this, is basically have one master page with the other content, a second one with the inner contents, and two others that just have the form tags and a placeholder inside them, and then dynamically choosing one master page over the other.

Is there a better way to do this or is this the correct way? thanks.

Update: I'm not sure my current idea is well expressed:

Base.master would have the outer contents, no inheritance.

Regular and Modified.master would have just the different form tags, both inherit from Base.Master

Shared.master would have the inner contents, inherit from Regular.Master and in case it requires the other form control, then it chooses the other master (which has the same `ContentPlaceHolderID` for `FormContent`), dynamically with something like this, maybe reading from web.config or the like

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "~/App_Shared/RegularWebForm.Master";
        this.MasterPageFile = "~/App_Shared/UrlRewritableWebForm.Master";
    }
```

The goal for this is being able to use the same Master page across three different applications for one same web domain.

The idea that my solution proposed would be that I have those four master page files in a given "App_Shared" folder, which is referenced via svn:externals from all the projects, so I don't have to repeat the code. The idea would be that I choose whether Shared.Master (which would be the functional base master page file for all three applications) uses the regular form or the user control in the current application, and that choice could be made by a setting in the web.config for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the master page code behind, you should be able to override OnInit (or OnLoad or in any number of other places) and determine when you need multipart encryption, and when you do, call:

```
Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

Even better:

Expose a boolean property:

```
public bool EncodeMe {get;set;};
```

In each form that uses the master control set

```
Master.EncodeMe = true; // or false of course
```

then in the master page use the bool to determine whether or not to encode.

Comment: it's not about whether it's encoded or not, the other form control is also encoded, but it's just encoded from codebehind like you suggest by default. The custom form control is used to make a custom url rewriting component work. While I still need regular forms for another url rewriting engine, but I still need both applications to share some common user interface like a site map.

Comment: No, the page doesn't determine anything, the web.config does. The master pages are shared across three applications, via `svn:externals`. The controls are indeed different: a regular html <form> tag vs a ASP.NET user control I created.

Comment: AH, That makes more sense...  yes I think you're on the right track.  You'll need a central BaseMasterPage which reads web.config to determine how it should behave, and in Master's code behind set the proper attributes based on the config file.  EACH project *will* need it's own master page, but they should inherit from BaseMasterPage as you suggested in the Q.